# AWS Amplify Authenticator React Native Tab Bar Navigation white screen instead of rendering my app

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-navigation, aws-amplify

I recently switched my app from AppAuth to Authentication with AWS Amplify for React Native and try to integrate the AWS Amplify Authenticator into my app. As described in the docs, I am wrapping Authenticator around my main App component of an already existing app in order to make sure a user can only view the app when signed in.

Everything is working as expected - the Login screen pops up and I can successfully sign in. Once signed in, I can see in the debugger that the components which shall only render after sign in get called and do all the background tasks as designed and I can also get the authState and authData from amplify which I need further on for holding the authorization state in my app and get the access token for performing API calls. Sounds as everything works as desired but there is one problem - when signed in, my user interface is not visible - there is just a blank white screen. So I am assuming that the Authenticator somehow either blocks my app from rendering or places a white layer on top of my app.

EDIT: OK I got some more details about this now - the problem only appears when using a TabNavigator inside my app. If I include one of my components directly without the TabNavigator, it works. Is there a known incompatibility between AWS Amplify and React Navigation Tab Navigation?

Thanks and best regards
The Smart Home Maker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK for everybody running into this problem in the future - got it fixed.

The problem was the following stylesheet attributes which are set by default for the container of the AWS amplify authenticator:

```
container: {
        ...
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        ...
    },
```

You have to actually remove them or if you can't remove them, set them to the default values:

```
container: {
            ...
            alignItems: 'stretch',
            justifyContent: 'flex-start',
            ...
        },
```

It's magic - once I had changed these stylesheet attributes, the Tab Navigator showed up :)

Comment: This then causes the app to share half the page with the login screen.

Comment: That’s possible but for me it is working exactly as expected